# How to forcefully timeout a process that spawns subprocesses

Tags: python, bash, timeout, subprocess, popen

I need to run processes (programs, bash scripts, etc) that might spawn other processes, but I also need to apply a timeout in case something gets hung up and I want program execution to continue after the timeout has expired.  I'm using the following run() function:

```
import subprocess, shlex, threading
from threading import Timer

def run(cmd, timeout_sec=5):
    def kill_proc(proc, timedout):
        timedout['value'] = True
        proc.kill()

    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        timedout = {'value': False}
        timer = threading.Timer(timeout_sec, kill_proc, [proc, timedout])
        timer.start()
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        timer.cancel()

        return stdout.decode('utf-8'), stderr.decode('utf-8'), proc.returncode, timedout['value']
    except Exception as e:
        print('Could not execute: %s - with error: %s' % (cmd, e))
        return '', '', 1, False
```

For the most part that works and it's able to gracefully timeout a call such as:

```
run(cmd='sleep 1m', timeout_sec=2)
```

Where it seems to get hung up is let's say I have the following bash script called sleeper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1m
```

and if I issue the following command:

```
run(cmd='sleeper.sh', timeout_sec=2)
```

it will sit there and wait for 1 minute until the command completes.  Is there a way such that I rewrite my run() function to forcefully timeout the process regardless of whatever child processes are spawned?

Answer (score 1):

Here's example code on how to achieve this in bash.  You might be able to apply it to your program:

```
$ date; timeout 1 sleep 5 ; date
Sat Dec  8 18:02:44 UTC 2018
Sat Dec  8 18:02:45 UTC 2018
```

So in short, see if prepending 'timeout duration'  to the beginning of your commands works.

Comment: I saw this work properly on CentOS but not on Mac OSX.

Comment: I removed my previous comments as they weren't needed - I tried your suggestion of prepending my commands with "timeout x" and it did in-fact work, but I'd really like, if possible, to handle everything within Python as it just seems a little kludgy. But yes, it does in-fact work, and I can also capture the errorlevel from the timeout command - unfortunately then I can't capture the errorlevel from the program I'm trying to execute. Not the end of the world, but it still adds another layer I'd rather handle within Python. I will still up-vote as it's definitely a creative and usable solution!